# Dynamic Range Setting

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set range dynamically. However, I have faced some error:

> Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object.

```
Sub calDailyGC()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Rng As Range

    numGC = Cells(46, 7).Value
    numDays = Cells(47, 7).Value

    Debug.Print numGC
    Debug.Print numDays

    For k = 3 To numDays + 1
        Set Rng = Range(Cells(k, 12), Cells(k, 9999))
        sumRate = 0
        For j = 1 To numGC
            rate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Rng, j)
            sumRate = sumRate + rate
        Next j
        avgGCRate = sumRate / numGC
    Next k
    Debug.Print avgGCRate

End Sub
```

Comment: `k` is not defined so `k` is `0` and row `0` does not exist so `Cells(k, 12)` fails. The code in your picture is not the code in your question! Be clear what we are talking about. • Also specify in which worksheet your cells and ranges are like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(…)` otherwise Excel cannot know it and guesses (and may guess wrong). • If you turn `ScreenUpdating = False`  don't forget to turn it `True` in the end. Same for `Calculation = xlCalculationManual` which you might want to turn back to automatic.

Comment: Aso make sure you use `Option Explicit` and declare **all** your variables properly.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks for your help! I resolved some of your comments in the updated code. And I have faced a new issue...

Comment: In which line is the errror? Please take into account also the other issues I mentioned in my comments. All of them are quite important to produce a solid code.

Comment: Please, specify both the workbook and worksheet for each range object. Otherwise VBA will refer to the active workbook and -sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object.
>
> rate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Rng, j)

Do not use `Rate`. It is a reserved word in VBA. You can read about `Rate` [here](https://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-rate-function.html)

Change it to say

```
LargeVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Rng, j)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works, I would like to check, for the line: Rng = Range(Cells(k, 12), Cells(k,9999))

I only need the even number cols, how should I do it? Aka Range(Cells(k,12), Cells(k, 14), ..., Cells(k,9998))

Comment: `For k = 3 To numDays + 1` If you want even numbers then start from `4` instead of `3` and use [STEP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement)

Comment: It's more of the Rng = Range(.Cells(k, 12), .Cells(k, 9999)), where I need to make 12, 14, 16, ..., 9998

Comment: Ah the columns you mean... In that case, please post a separate question for that and we can handle that query there :)

Comment: Cheers (: I have shared the question with you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56770247/creating-a-range-with-only-the-even-number-col