# Creating a range with only the even number col

Tags: excel, vba

I am interested to have `rng` select only even columns (within Col 12 to 9999). I have attached my code below. Please assist, thank you!

```
Sub calDailyGC()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set w = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Dim gc As Double

    numGC = Cells(46, 7).Value
    numDays = Cells(47, 7).Value

    For k = 3 To numDays + 1
        Rng = Range(Cells(k, 12), Cells(k, 9999))
        sumRate = 0
        For j = 1 To numGC
            gc = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Rng, j)
            Debug.Print gc
            sumRate = sumRate + gc
        Next j
    Next k
    avgGCRate = sumRate / numGC

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of `Rng = Range(Cells(k, 12), Cells(k, 9999))`:

```
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    i = 12
    Set Rng = .Cells(k, i)
    i = i + 2
    Do While i < 9999
        Set Rng = Union(Rng, .Cells(k, i))
        i = i + 2
    Loop
End With
```